# How to parse multi key-value data in GreenPlum or postgres

Tags: json

I have a table in my DWH (GreenPlum).
This table contains following colums:

"ID" int
,INFO json

There are many different types of json possible to be in this table

For example:
for id 1 json will be like this: `{"type":"GAME_SCORE","type":"GAME_SCORE","value":"0"}`
for id 2 json will be like this:

{"type":"Game_analyzing"
,"type":"detail_game_analyzing"
,"first_game":{"game_date":"2022-10-12"
,"stadium_name":"Acapulco"
,"arbitr_manager":{
"first_name":"Jack"
,"last_name":"Black"
,"phone_number":"+1323446943"}
,"decision_type":{
"id":19
,"name":"admitted"}
,"last_game":{"game_date":"2022-11-15"
,"stadium_name":"Acapulco"
,"arbitr_manager":{
"first_name":"Marshal"
,"last_name":"Peterson"
,"phone_number":"+42831432"}
,"decision_type":{
"id":56
,"name":"admitted"}
}

how we would like to use this data:

- we would like to use filters on first "type" in where clause

what we are expecting:

- by final result we are expecting a table like this:
  for id 1 it will be:

| value1 | Value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| type | GAME_SCORE | 0 |

for id 2 it will be

| value1 |  | value2 | value3 |  | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| type | detail_game_analyzing |  | null |  |  |
| first_game | game_date | 2022-10-12 | null |  |  |
| first_game | stadium_name | Acapulco | null |  |  |
| first_game | arbitr_manager | first_name | Jack |  |  |
| first_game | arbitr_manager | last_name | Black |  |  |
| first_game | arbitr_manager | phone_number | +1323446943 |  |  |
| first_game | decision_type | id | 19 |  |  |
| first_game | decision_type | name | admitted |  |  |

same logic for last_game and it data

I know we need to use recursive query here, but i have no idea how to do it for id#2 or any another json structure that contains random number of sub-json.
Is this even possible?

I can write code only for example on id #1, but this is not enough